# Django deploy to Heroku No module named 'django_heroku'

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm tryin to deploy to Heroku and before this error I was getting:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django-tables2'

Then I installed django-heroku via pip install django-heroku, followed the instructions on how to set it up.

I disabled the collect static for heroku pushed my master branch and everything is fine, but once I do:

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

I get the:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_heroku'
```

the complete traceback is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 341, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 225, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 219, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 153, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/GPC/settings.py", line 14, in <module>
    import django_heroku
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_heroku'
```

I have in my settings at the top:

```
import os
import django_heroku
```

and in the very bottom:

```
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

in my requirements.txt I have django-heroku

The master branch is updated and I just can find how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that it was not added to the module, it was needed to be added to the virtual env and then do the pip freeze, with that it was solved.

Comment: Hi, can you let me know how you fixed this. I am getting the same error message on Heroku. I have it installed via pip, also imported on settings.py but it still gives me the deplyment error

Comment: use pipenv freeze not pip freeze