# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_heroku' even after installation

Tags: python, django, heroku, pycharm

I set up a Django project in a venv and installed django_heroku in the root folder of my project.
When I run 'python manage.py runserver' I get the following error:

```
../settings.py", line 15, in <module>
import django_heroku
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_heroku'
```

This is my requirements.txt, all of these are installed:

```
asgiref==3.5.2
dj-database-url==1.0.0
Django==4.1
django-extensions==3.2.0
django-heroku==0.3.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
psycopg2==2.9.3
psycopg2-binary==2.9.3
python-dateutil==2.8.2
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.2
whitenoise==6.2.0
```

Relevant parts of settings.py:

```
import os
import django_heroku
...
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
...
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

This is my Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn twatsite.wsgi
```

[I have tried changing my Procfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62193007/django-heroku-and-psycopg2-installed-but-shows-import-django-heroku-modulenotfo)

[I have checked the venv/lib/site-packages folder and found django_heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61378941/django-deploy-to-heroku-no-module-named-django-heroku)

This is the structure of my folders:
[image]

I have also tried moving the files in Twatter/twatsite/twatsite/.. one folder higher to Twatter/twatsite/.. This did not work and I moved the files back.
Any pointers on how to solve or troublehsoot this issue are very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that I was in a venv inside a venv. So a virtual environment inside another virtual environment.

```
(Twatter) (base) name@laptop twatsite %
```

I deleted my venv folder and exited the venv's I was in by doing 'deactivate' followed by 'conda deactivate' (because it told me to). After this I created a new venv folder within Twatter/ with 'python3 -m venv twatvenv' and activated it again with 'source twatvenv/bin/activate'.

After this I reinstalled the requirements with:

```
pip install -r twatsite/requirements.txt
```

Now I could run the server from Twatter/twatsite/ with 'python manage.py runserver'!